# PHP mailer not sending mails to particular groups

Tags: php, email

Am using PHP mailer for sending emails.For individual users and for some groups i am able to send mails but for some other groups the mails are not going.Am using Microsoft exchange server for the mails.And there are no errors shown in the log file in the host.

PHP mailer code:

```
require 'class.phpmailer.php';
$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->isSMTP();                                     
$mail->Host = 'email.domain.com';  
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               
$mail->Username = 'username@domain.com';                
$mail->Password = '********';                          
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            
$mail->Port = 587;                                  
$mail->setFrom('username@domain.com');
$addresses = 'Recipients@domain.com';
$mail->isHTML(true);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You log setup as debug level? and you can check mail queue? and if you mail queue is empty and you error log is empty, then remote mail server don't geting you email, maybe mail removed in spam automatically or resend mail to back(From address in your email). Also you can check this from `username@domain.com` for apruve(sorry I can't how to correct write this word) returned this mails or not.

Comment: I am checking the erroe.log file and even in spam there is no trace of that email..is threr anything to do with the port no ?

Comment: Email in `from` method `setFrom()` exist? If you only send mail you can don't open 25(smtp port, just for example) port to internet, if you want received email on your server, you need get 25 (email port) is opened for received mail.